# How to create a macro in Powerpoint 2013 to record presentation to .wmv

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am a new for ppt-vba. Powerpoint 2013 can record presentation to wmv file.
But the procedure is complicated. How could I create a marco to finish my job easily?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your use-case, but if you need to record a presentation and get it as a video (mp4? Does that suffice?), you could use Presentious (https://presentio.us)

For example: http://presentio.us/view/p1tcHs

It's free. It's web-based.

Answer (score 0):

You can save directly to video in PowerPoint 2013 in both MP4 and WMV formats without the use of any additional software. This is the macro that will save your presentation to a WMV video file:

```
' Pass a file name, including path, in the format "C:\Temp\myVideo.wmv"
Sub SaveToVideo(MyFileName As String)
  With ActivePresentation
    .SaveAs MyFileName, ppSaveAsWMV
    ' You can also save as MP4 with the following line
    '.SaveAs MyFileName, ppSaveAsMP4
  End With
End Sub
```